# CakePHP FileEngine::clear takes very much CPU time

Tags: php, cakephp

Last week I migrated my CentOS server to another machine.
VDS Server hardwares are very similar. 
I tried my best to replicate server behaviour in new machine.
CakePHP 2.4.4, PHP 5.4.26. I serve PHP as apache module. XCache 3.1.0.

(But it seems like I get too much CPU times in certain times.
For example everything works for 10 minutes but for 2 minutes my CPU becomes 100%, then it becomes %5 and after 4-5 minutes I get CPU 100% again)

It seems like in my CakePHP application

```
FileEngine::clear()
```

too much time. How can I diagnose/debug why [FileEngine::clear](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.4.4/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php#L223) takes too much time ?

You can check code run times from images:
Image 1: http://s29.postimg.org/qfj26aq8n/shot1.jpg
Image 2: http://s9.postimg.org/uzwh1a5i7/shot2.jpg

Also note that in my error.log file I get these errors:

```
Warning: Warning (2): is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/example.com/:/tmp/:/usr/share/fonts/) in [/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 265]
Trace:
is_dir - [internal], line ??
FileEngine::_clearDirectory() - CORE/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 265
FileEngine::clear() - CORE/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 247
FileEngine::gc() - CORE/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php, line 100
Cache::_buildEngine() - CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 184
Cache::config() - CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 151
include - APP/Config/bootstrap.php, line 101
Configure::bootstrap() - CORE/Cake/Core/Configure.php, line 92
include - CORE/Cake/bootstrap.php, line 175
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 93
```

Note that in Apache configuration `open_basedir`[(p)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) setting is like this:

```
{WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}:/usr/share/fonts/
```

Edit:
I logged timestamps in `FileEngine::clear` and `FileEngine::_clearDirectory`. But there exists no strange times. Slowest call has 0.3 seconds. Average is 0.01 seconds. But when I check `FileEngine::clear()` call time I see 90-95 seconds in peak times.

Comment: What happens when debug is set to 0? Might be a stupid question, but perhaps it helps debugging the problem :)

Comment: My debug is zero in core.php :) `Configure::write('debug', 0);`

Comment: Hmm, could you try adding some timestamps in the cake FileEngine? Just to check on what line it is crashing? And how many files are in the cache? Maybe there are just a lot of files? Shouldn't matter I guess, but it might the problem?

Comment: @Jelmer Thank you. Really there exists too many files in folder. Nearly 30k-40k files. But when I log timestamps in methods, there exists no strange times. I edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days I found solution. The problem is like this:

In `/app/tmp/cache/` folder I have some folders like this:

```
/app/tmp/cache/mydata1/
/app/tmp/cache/mydata2/
/app/tmp/cache/mydata3/
```

Each of these folders has 10k-15k files.
So in every minute/hour garbage collection runs and `FileEngine::clear()` runs and checks for these folders. Checking these folders takes too much CPU time.

Inside app/Config/bootstrap.php there exists Cache settings like this:

```
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));
```

To disable garbage collection by changing probability to zero:

```
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File', 'probability' => 0));
```

> probability Probability of hitting a cache gc cleanup. Setting to 0
>   will disable cache::gc from ever being called automatically.

http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Cache.html#_config

For example I had another cache configuration like this:

```
Cache::config('30secs', array(
    'engine' => "File",
    'duration' => '+30 seconds',
    'path' => CACHE,
    'prefix' => 'cake_element_30secs_'
));
```

Then CakePHP will check for temp folder in every 30 seconds. So it can delete unnecessary cache files. You can also disable garbage collection by changing probability to zero.

My recommendation is, if you have too many files in `/app/tmp/cache/` folder you should move your data to another folder so you shouldn't spend your CPU for this.